# updating a kitchen light with a LED unit

Tags: wiring

I went to the panel which is marked but not correct...I flipped off every breaker one at a time but the light did not go off.I did not shut off the main..I lowered the old unit and there are 2 sets of wires black and wht. only 3 wires on the old unit...should I just clean the wires with the MAIN switch off? Then copy the old connections?  The old light is a circular florescent type the wires look like the same color..

Comment: You missed a breaker. Step 1 is to map your panel so you can work safely on this and future projects. That said, its not clear what you're asking. Yes, you should disconnect power. Yes, you should connect the new fixture correctly.

Comment: Where are you? If you have a 120-V circuit which you think is not protected by its own individual 15-A or 20-A breaker or fuse, then you should investigate before proceeding. I think you will find a breaker if you look.

Comment: What is the manufacturer, age, and type of the electrical panel?

Comment: Flip them off one at a time but don’t flip them back on until you find a winner. Bring a flashlight if it’s dark walking to your panel.

Comment: Is your panel a modern type with a single main breaker which shuts off power to all circuits including the 240-V ones? Or is it the older "split bus" type (like my 47-year-old GE panel) in which the 240-V breakers are in an upper section and the 120-V breakers are below? Are there unused slots for 120-V breakers or is the panel full?

Comment: Yes it's a Square D late 70's It has a breaker just for the main.The larger breakers are at the top with the others below...I think that the ceiling lights are on a loop like I have seen in other post. About 2 yrs ago we had the bathroom redone and there was 1 set of wires also hooked up in there but the guy cut and terminated because it now had it's own breaker-and a GFI. Maybe that is why the light on the kitchen won't go off with the breaker? So I guess I will shut the main off and copy the old connections.. There was never a problem with the light switch. I am going with a dimmer for LED's

Comment: @DeanSwift if you don’t have an individual breaker for this light...STOP, DO NOT PASS GO.. call an electrician.  This is a big issue.

Comment: I know that , I have contacted on..He said with the loop and cutting the one to the bathroom from that old light they may need to shut off two breakers but he was not sure yet. Thanks

Comment: It’s not any safer if two circuits are crossed.  If that’s the case GET A NEW ELECTRICIAN.  Seriously the things you are saying here are troubling.

Comment: He did not do the wiring it was the existing setup...That was an assumption..He is going to check both areas and the panel...Thanks..

Comment: Found out today that the panel door was marked wrong. since the time a dryer was added the label marked dryer was the one for the lights in the kitchen-2 bedrooms and a outlet ..So all is solved. Thanks for the replies.